# Проблемы с обратной связью. не работает скрипт mail.php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, email, sendmail

Использую  скрипт обратной связи для  доставки   письма  на мою почту.
При переносе  на  другой  хостинг  почему-то  перестали приходить письма.

Проверял функцию mail() - работает.
Для проверки использовал этот код:

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
if (mail("a.i.khmelovsky@gmail.com", "Test mail", "Проверка отправки почты")) {
      echo "ok";
} else {
       echo "error";}
?>
```

а Вот этот код отказывается работать. **Письма не приходят**, ошибок в консоли нет.

```
<?php
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_POST["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_POST["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_POST["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

    $project_name = trim($_GET["project_name"]);
    $admin_email  = trim($_GET["admin_email"]);
    $form_subject = trim($_GET["form_subject"]);

    foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
            $message .= "
            " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
                <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
    }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
 ?>
```

Пробовал подтягивать этот скрипт с другого  хостинга -  работает.   Получается  именно этот скрипт не  хочет работать  на  этом  хостинге. Не могу понять в чем причина. Хостинг Ukraine.com.ua

Прошу помощи у  знающих людей  для решения  этой проблемы. Заранее Спасибо

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
        <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="название сайта">
        <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="a.i.khmelovsky@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="тема письма">
        <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="name">
     <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Введіть Ваше ім'я">
     </div>
     <div class="phone-m">
     <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="+380 123 45 67">
     </div>
     <div class="email">
     <input type="text" name="E-mail" placeholder="Email">
     </div>
     <div class="appeal">
        <textarea cols="40" rows="7"  class="dsfsd" placeholder="Що вас турбує?"></textarea>
     </div>
    <button>Надіслати</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //E-mail Ajax Send
    $("form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-content/themes/neuro/mail.php", //Change
            data: th.serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
            setTimeout(function() {
                // Done Functions
                th.trigger("reset");
            }, 1000);
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция mail подразумевает только отправку писем, т.е. если в первом листинге Вы получаете ok, то сама функция отправила письмо, но совершенно не гарантируется прием этих писем почтовым сервером, потому что IP с которого Вы отправили не принадлежит gmail, письмо получает большой спам-вес и частенько отфильтровывается почтовым сервером даже не доходя до папки "Спам".

Решений два, точнее два с половиной.

Первое - (если возможно) используйте почту для домена которую дает вам хостинг или почтовые сервисы (например Яндекс)

Второе - используйте отправку писем через SMTP авторизацией, **этот метод самый надежный** и я рекомендую именно его, а инструментарий на Ваш выбор. Я использую вот этот класс http://vk-book.ru/otpravka-pisem-cherez-smtp-s-avtorizaciej-na-php/

Answer (score 0):

Кодировка скрипта PHP должна быть UTF-8 пересохрани сам документ. Ну и на локальной машине оно и не заработает, проверяй на хостинге.