# Почему с хостинга не отправляются уведомления на gmail?

Tags: php, sendmail, gmail

Настроил на локальном сервере отправку уведомлений о новых заявках на сайте, все работало прекрасно, но после того как залил сайт на хостинг - уведомления не приходят. В чем может быть проблема? Подскажите плиз. Кстати заливал еще на пробный хостинг zzz.com.ua, так вот с него тоже все работает, а на gpdhost.com нет...

```
require_once "SendMailSmtpClass.php";
    $mailSMTP = new SendMailSmtpClass('bookboxsg@gmail.com', '**************', 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', 'BookBox', 465);
    $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: BookBox <bookboxsg@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $result =  $mailSMTP->send('bookboxsg@gmail.com', 'New phone', $request["phone"], $headers);
```

Comment: Попробуйте пропинговать, узнайте ip адрес и проверьте его в спам списках (в гугле найдите "проверить ip в спам листах онлайн") и посмотрите. Бывает что некоторые адреса от хостингов заносятся в эти списки благодаря некоторым нехорошим людям

Comment: Без spf и dkim работать с Gmail проблематично

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблемы с обратной связью. не работает скрипт mail.php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709395/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-mail-php)

Comment: Ответ тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709395/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-mail-php/709789#709789